# Keynote: How to skip "open presentation" window?

Tags: macos, keynote, iwork

When I launch Keynote on my new MacBook Pro, the window used to open existing presentations is opened:

[image: Example of window]

I would like to simply open a new document instead, but cannot find an option for this.

Is there any way for me to set Keynote to default to creating a new presentation, instead of defaulting to opening an existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is determined by the ‘NSShowAppCentricOpenPanelInsteadOfUntitledFile’ key. Setting this preference to false will show the new document view by default.

```
defaults write com.apple.iWork.Keynote NSShowAppCentricOpenPanelInsteadOfUntitledFile -bool false
```

If you would like a new document to open with a set theme instead of with the theme chooser, go to Keynote Preferences and set For New Documents: Use theme.

[image]